# Formatting kable cells with individual colors in RMarkdown and Quarto

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto, kable

I have a table with numeric data and want to assign individual colors, depending on a certain condition, e.g. negative cells in red and positive in blue.

This works well with `kable(escape=FALSE)`:

```
library("dplyr")
library("knitr")
library("kableExtra")
set.seed(123)

highlight <- function(x) {
  x <- ifelse(is.na(x), "", x)
  ifelse(x < 0, cell_spec(x, color="red"), cell_spec(x, color="blue"))
}

matrix(sample(-4:4), nrow=3) |>
  data.frame() |>
  mutate(across(1:3, function(x) highlight(x))) |>
  kable(escape=FALSE)
```

[image: table shows colors]

### Additional styling

But after adding additional styling with `kable_styling`:

```
matrix(sample(-4:4), nrow=3) |>
  data.frame() |>
  mutate(across(1:3, function(x) highlight(x))) |>
  kable(escape=FALSE) |>
  kable_styling(font_size = 12)
```

... the printed table shows only raw **HTML code** instead of colors:

[image]

### What has changed between versions?

With older versions of **R**, `kable_styling` works as expected. I tested it again right now with **R** version 3.6.3 using RMarkdown and dplyr pipes. However, with recent versions of **R** (4.3.2 or 4.3.3) and the recent set of packages, it prints only code, regardless if I use RMarkdown or Quarto, native or dplyr pipes, html or latex output.

So I wonder, what has changed between versions and if there is any workaround?

Comment: Hmm, surprising, because I can reproduce the error on two different computers, both with most recent updates of R, RStudio and all packages. The OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Ah okay. I just checked. I had an older version of `kableExtra` aka 1.3.4. After updating to 1.4.0 I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks, that explains the reason. In the meantime, I played around with the `format` argument of `kable`, that partly solves the issue. If I set `format="html"` explicitly, I get the desired result. It seems that the default is now `pipe`. I say, "partly solved", because an explicit setting is not portable between html and latex, at least not automatically.

Comment: This was already reported on GH. See https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/811. You can fix that by using `kbl()` instead of `kable()` or by using `kable(escape = FALSE, format="html")`